# Counting nonidentity elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

> Prove that the number of elements $x$ of a finite group $G$ such that $x^7 = e$ is odd.

Let $x$ be a non-identity element of $G$ with $x^7 = e.$ Then $Ord(x) = 7$ meaning $(x^i)^7 = e$ for all $1\le i \le 6.$  Thus there are $6n \; x's \in G$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $x^7 = e.$ Also, $e^7 = e$ and $6n + 1$ is odd.

How did they determine the number of non identity $x$ to be $6n$?

Comment: they assumed there was $n$ distinct cyclic subgroups of order $7$, each of them has $6$ non-identity elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you find $\;e\neq x\in G\;$ with $\;x^7=e\;$,  you find in fact six such *non-identity* elements: $\;x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6\;$ , as you can easily check, so in the end there will  always be (in a finite group) $\;6k\;$ such non-identity elements, and adding to this the identity you get an odd number of such elements.

Answer (score 0):

These elements have their own cycles. i.e., if $x$ is one such element, then all of $x, x^2, \ldots, x^6,x^7=e$ must be in $G$. Any if $y \in G$ is not a part of this cycle, then it has its own just like it.

Hence, the number $N$ of elements in $G$ with this property depends on the number of such disjoint cycles, say $n$. Then, $N = 6n+1$.

Comment: It doesn't say all the non-identity elements in the group have order $7$.

Comment: @snulty thanks, corected